# Calling a stored procedure in a different database then the default

Tags: database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute stored procedures in drupal?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32708/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-in-drupal)

I am trying to call a stored procedure in drupal.  I was wondering if anyone knew the syntax to call a stored procedure.  One thing about the stored proc is that it is inside a different database then the default database.  Any help would be greatly aprreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: @kiamlaluno Should I flag questions like this in future (where there are a couple of duplicates) rather than just comment?

Comment: You can also vote to close it. The mainly duplicated question is the first one; the fact the database is not the default one is secondary, and answered by the second question. Flagging with a custom reason should be reserved for very old questions nobody would notice, especially if the question is blatantly off-topic, and possibly after having voted to close it. (In this way, it doesn't seem the moderator decided to close the question for unknown reasons.) Keep in mind this is my thought; different moderators can handle the situation differently.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for the comment you left before; it made me notice the question was a duplicate.

Comment: Im sorry but you cant close a question when the other question you are referring to doesn't get looked at or answered!!  On top of that, both you claim top be duplicates but neither one truly answer the question.